# Why is one of my strings in C working and the other not?

Tags: c, string

I've been making a program that receives a starting time, an ending time and outputs the difference (all in HH:MM format).
My solution was to make strings for the time values and then extract the numbers off of the strings. So I have 2 strings: char entryTime[5] and char exitTime[5].

I made a function that receives the 2 strings to return the difference, and that's where my problem is. The function worked for the exitTime, it extracted the hours and minutes separatly just fine. But the entryTime part was always giving wrong outputs.
I started filling the function with printf to output all variables involved, and I traced it back to the string itself. For some reason, the string received by the function as a parameter for the entryTime[5] was empty. The exitTime[5] string, received the same way, as a parameter on the function, was fine.
Also, for some reason, when using printf to output the last 2 chars of the entryTime string, it works fine, even though the string itself is empty when printing it.

Creation of the strings:
`char entryTime[5], exitTime[5];`
Giving value to the strings:
`scanf("\n%[^\n]", entryTime);`
`scanf("\n%[^\n]", exitTime);`
Calling the function:
`calculateParkingTime(entryTime, exitTime, &dH);`

This is the part of the function that is not working properly:

```
    //entryTime 
    printf("\n >%s", entryTime); //outputs nothing
    aux[0] = entryTime[0]; 
    aux[1] = entryTime[1];
    hAux = atoi(aux);
    printf("\n-%i\n", hAux); //outputs 0
    aux[0] = entryTime[3];
    aux[1] = entryTime[4];
    mAux = atoi(aux);
    printf("\n-%i\n", mAux); //outputs correctly
    mAux += hAux*60;
    T1 = mAux;
```

This is the exitTime part that works fine, for comparision:

```
    //exitTime
    printf("\n>%s", exitTime); //outputs correctly
    aux[0] = exitTime[0];
    aux[1] = exitTime[1];
    hAux = atoi(aux);
    printf("\n-%i\n", hAux); //outputs correctly
    aux[0] = exitTime[3];
    aux[1] = exitTime[4];
    mAux = atoi(aux);
    printf("\n-%i\n", mAux); //outputs correctly
    mAux += hAux*60;
    T2 = mAux;
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. What is, for example, `aux` and how is it initialized. What is `horaEntrada` and how is it initialized? And so on. Also please show us the output you have, versus the output you expect. And of course also please show us possible input.

Comment: "hh:mm" is 5 characters. `char entryTime[5] and char exitTime[5]`... You're using those as if they were C strings... There's no room for the required trailing NUL that makes a C string... Don't be stingy! Bump up the dimensions of those two arrays to something bigger...

Comment: Oh, is it because there's no space for the "\0" at the end of the C string?

Comment: Unrelated, but please use `fgets` to read whole lines. Besides being much simpler to use than `scanf`, `fgets` is also much safer since you provide the buffer size to there's less chance of buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a time with the format `HH:MM` the destination array must have at least 6 bytes: 5 for the characters and an extra one for the null terminator.

Similarly, the temporary array `aux` must have at least 3 bytes and you must set a null terminator at `aux[2]`.  Note however that there is no need for this intermediate array as `atoi()` will stop the conversion at the first non digit character.  Note also that you could use `sscanf()` to convert the strings using `"%d:%d"`.

The reason one seems to work and not the other is you have undefined behavior, which means the programs may appear to work or not in unpredictable ways.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char entryTime[10];
    char exitTime[10];
    int hAux, mAux, T1, T2;

    printf("Enter entry and exit times (HH:MM): ");
    if (scanf("%9s %9s", entryTime, exitTime) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (sscanf(entryTime, "%d:%d", &hAux, &mAux) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s\n", entryTime);
        return 1;
    }
    T1 = hAux * 60 + mAux;

    if (sscanf(exitTime, "%d:%d", &hAux, &mAux) != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid format: %s\n", exitTime);
        return 1;
    }
    T2 = hAux * 60 + mAux;

    printf("elapsed time: %d minutes\n", T2 - T1);
    return 0;
}
```